# How to get a <th> inside a <tr> with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the headers from a table that are part of the `<thead>` tag. I want to access the second `<tr>` tag, where we can find all the `<th>` of interest.

```
<table id="tablaDatos" class="general">
<thead>

<tr><td rowspan="2" class="th r0"></td><th id="c_A0" colspan="52" class="r0">Índice</th></tr>

<tr>

<th id="c_B0" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2019T4</th>
<th id="c_B1" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2019T3</th>
<th id="c_B2" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2019T2</th>
<th id="c_B3" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2019T1</th
><th id="c_B4" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2018T4</th>
<th id="c_B5" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2018T3</th>
<th id="c_B6" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2018T2</th>
<th id="c_B7" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2018T1</th>
<th id="c_B8" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2017T4</th>
<th id="c_B9" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2017T3</th>
<th id="c_B10" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2017T2</th>
<th id="c_B11" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2017T1</th>
<th id="c_B12" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2016T4</th>
<th id="c_B13" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2016T3</th>
<th id="c_B14" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2016T2</th>
<th id="c_B15" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2016T1</th>
<th id="c_B16" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2015T4</th>
<th id="c_B17" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2015T3</th>
<th id="c_B18" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2015T2</th>
<th id="c_B19" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2015T1</th>
<th id="c_B20" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2014T4</th>
<th id="c_B21" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2014T3</th>
<th id="c_B22" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2014T2</th>
<th id="c_B23" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2014T1</th>
<th id="c_B24" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2013T4</th>
<th id="c_B25" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2013T3</th>
<th id="c_B26" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2013T2</th>
<th id="c_B27" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2013T1</th>
<th id="c_B28" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2012T4</th>
<th id="c_B29" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2012T3</th>
<th id="c_B30" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2012T2</th>
<th id="c_B31" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2012T1</th>
<th id="c_B32" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2011T4</th>
<th id="c_B33" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2011T3</th>
<th id="c_B34" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2011T2</th>
<th id="c_B35" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2011T1</th>
<th id="c_B36" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2010T4</th>
<th id="c_B37" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2010T3</th>
<th id="c_B38" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2010T2</th>
<th id="c_B39" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2010T1</th>
<th id="c_B40" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2009T4</th>
<th id="c_B41" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2009T3</th>
<th id="c_B42" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2009T2</th>
<th id="c_B43" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2009T1</th>
<th id="c_B44" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2008T4</th>
<th id="c_B45" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2008T3</th>
<th id="c_B46" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2008T2</th>
<th id="c_B47" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2008T1</th>
<th id="c_B48" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2007T4</th>
<th id="c_B49" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2007T3</th>
<th id="c_B50" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2007T2</th>
<th id="c_B51" headers="c_A0" class="r1 cols">2007T1</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

The problem is that my code only gives me the first header (2019T4), but not all the other `<th>` inside the second `<tr>`

Hereunder is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Datos.htm?t=25171#!tabs-tabla"
req = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
table = html.find("table")
header = []
for cols in table.findAll('th',class_="r1 cols"):  
    header.append(cols)
print(header)
```

Comment: Have a look at `print(html.thead)`, I'm afraid the data you collect from `requests` does not contain the rows you're looking for (which you are seeing using the inspector). Is that right?

Comment: The url in your code `https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Datos.htm?t=25171#!tabs-tabla` does not have the html structure you shows in your question. You are probably using a wrong url and expecting a different result.

Comment: Please use 'inspect' function of your browser to confirm the html structure.

Comment: I've inspected the url again and it seems to be correct.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The values contained in the th tags: 2019T4, 2019T3,2019T2, 2019T1,2018T4....

Answer (score 0):

You can grab just the headers using a different url which is where you actually select the periods to return data for

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=25171')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print([i.text for i in soup.select('#periodo option')])
```

Selections should be made at that url to then return specific data of interest. We would need the exact selections if you intend for us to replicate the entire table (which is not listed as a requirement in your question).